# Transforming RandomAccessSlice to RandomAccessCollection

Tags: arrays, swift

When we try to retrieve a range of elements from an `Array`, we get back an `ArraySlice`:

```
let array = [1, 3, 5, 2]
let arraySlice = array[..<2] // elements up to index 1 == [1, 3]
```

We can transform it back to the `Array` type like so:

```
let arrayFromSlice = Array(arraySlice)
```

---

Let's say you want to create a method that returns the first 3 elements of any `RandomAccessCollection`:

```
func first3Elements<T: RandomAccessCollection>(_ c: T) -> T {
  let slice = c.prefix(3)

  // COMPILER ERROR: non-nominal type 'T' 
  // does not support explicit initialization
  return T(slice)
}
```

Is it possible to perform this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my first attempt using type erasure but I guess there are better solutions.

```
func first3Elements<T>(_ c: AnyRandomAccessCollection<T>) -> AnyRandomAccessCollection<T> {
    let slice = c.prefix(3)
    return AnyRandomAccessCollection(slice)
}

let array = AnyRandomAccessCollection([1, 2, 3, 4])
let result = first3Elements(array)

for x in result {
    print(x)
}
```

Comment: @MartinR do you have any idea?