# Redundant conformance of "HomeTabBarViewController" to protocol 'UITabBarControllerDelegate' iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Firstly I'm new in iOS programming. I can't implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. I get this error :

> Redundant conformance of "HomeTabBarViewController" to protocol
>   'UITabBarControllerDelegate'

```
class HomeTabBarViewController: UITabBarController , UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        print("didSelect viewController")
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("didSelect item")
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You save my time thank you again :)

Comment: @MartinR Yep it's a possible duplicate (p.s. are you able to take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233398/transforming-randomaccessslice-to-randomaccesscollection) ;-)

Comment: The class name in the error message does not match the class name in the code. Are these the same (just with one changed before posting), or is there a separate `HomeTabBarViewController` defined somewhere? If so, can you post code for that?

Comment: @MichaelHulet I edited question. thank you for your interest